# Serialization on runtime and partial Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have a below class as example

```
class Employee implements Serializable{
transient String x;
String y;

Date d= new Date("5/10/1984");

}
```

1)Can i serialize x at run time?
2)Can i serialize only month and day not year in Date?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html look at the description of the `writeObject` and `readObject` methods.

Answer (score 0):

1) Date internally consists of a long (ms since 1.1.1970 utc). Month and day then are computed from the long and the current time zone. You can serialize a date, it will basically transmit the embedded long.
2) You  can't, however you simply might serialize the strings. Beware, if this is deserialized in another locale this might create unexpected behaviour.